# sequence of error messages for required field in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, validation

I have a content type which has 4 CCK fields.
Field name are :

1. field_device_data_card_id
2. field_device_model
3. field_device_type
4. field_device_id

These fields are in their respective sequence.

all fields are marked as mandatory. when i click submit button without filling any data in required fields, it generate error messages for mandatory fields but the sequence of error messages are not proper.
it is displayed in following sequence ->

1. Device Data Card ID field is required.
2. Device ID field is required.
3. Device Model field is required.
4. Please select a device type.

while it should be like ->

1. Device Data Card ID field is required.
2. Device Model field is required.
3. Please select a device type.
4. Device ID field is required.

Please provide me a solution so that i can sequence the error messages.

Thanks

Comment: Would you detail the type of the field as well, please ? e.g: field_device_id is an integer field, model is a text field, etc ?

Comment: 1. field_device_data_card_id -> Text field                            2. field_device_model -> Text field                                                  3. field_device_type -> Select list                                              4. field_device_id -> Text field                                         Thanks

Answer (score 1):

.. add your custom validator via hook_form_alter and:

```
function form_name_validate($form, &$form_state) {
$tmp_msg = drupal_get_messages('error');
// change order or modify on your own of $tmp_msg
drupal_set_message($tmp_msg,'error');
}
```